# Getting elements in the Nth column using JQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following html code

```
<div style="column-count: 3;">
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>


<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It divides the ul's into three columns. Now i want to get all the elements of first column only using JQuery. Is this possible ??

Comment: I don't think JS has the ability to tell the layout of the document. There is a solution though, which requires you retrieving the `offset` property of individual `<li>` elements: those with the lowest values are on the first column (again, this strategy will not work in a rtl reading direction).

Comment: You can try fetching ul tags separately into new div tags from divs.

Comment: Could you give a code sample?

Comment: Stuart gave the example.      <div class="myUls">
    <ul>....
</div>

$('.myUls ul:first-child').find('li');

Comment: @Terry Whether RTL or LTR, "first" column is made of the items having the same offset as the first item of the first list so your solution should work in both cases if you just compare this value to all others instead of keeping the _lowest_

Comment: @FelipeAls can u please elaborate ???

Comment: 1/ Loop over all items and get their X position (offset). 2/ Keep the very first one as a reference. It's part of the first column. 3/ Compare all X positions to that one. When equal it's also part of the first column (RTL special case: when not equal - for columns 2 and 3 - it'll still be lower than the first column because it's displayed from right to left so it can't be a test criteria)

Comment: What if i want to move the last element of first column to the start of next column ??

Answer (score 1):

To get the `li`'s of the first `ul` then you can do:

```
$('ul:first-child').find('li');
```

To be more specific, put a selector on your `div`:

```
<div class="myUls">
    <ul>....
</div>

$('.myUls ul:first-child').find('li');
```

Comment: Ths first column (displayed) may not be the first list if items are taller/smaller than other items (it's visual)

Answer (score 0):

Use `eq` or `nth-child`:

```
$div.find('ul:eq(0) li')
$div.find('ul:nth-child(1) li')
```

Notice that `eq` is "0-indexed" and `nth-child` is "1-indexed".

Also JQuery has shortcuts `first-child` and `last-child`.

Answer (score 0):

use the [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector

```
$( "ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2)" )
```

will selects the second `li` of the first `ul`

Answer (score 0):

You can get all first `li` value by this:

`$("div ul").each(function(t){ alert( $(this).find("li:first").text() ); } );`

similarly you can use `nth-child` also..

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachin4dotnet/2axrjxsa/)

```js
$("div ul").each(function()
 { 
   $("#sa").text( $("#sa").text() + " > " +
      $(this).find("li:first").text();
         //$(this).find("li:nth-child(1)").text();
       );
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="column-count: 3;">
<ul>
<li>1.1</li>
<li>1.2</li>
<li>1.3</li>
<li>1.4</li>
</ul>


<ul>
<li>2.1</li>
<li>2.2</li>
<li>2.3</li>
<li>2.4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>3.1</li>
<li>3.2</li>
<li>3.3</li>
<li>3.4</li>
</ul>
</div>

<span id="sa"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>John</li>
        <li>Karl</li>
        <li>Brandon</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Sam</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Glen</li>
        <li>Tane</li>
        <li>Ralph</li>
        <li>David</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
    $( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).append( "<span> - 2nd!</span>" );
    </script>

    https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/
```